# how can I add multiple command in jmeter

Tags: shell, jmeter

I'm using jmeter in macOS(Big sur) to test some actions.
Before main test, I am trying to use JMeter naturally.
What I wanna do is to execute multiple commands by jmeter(OS Process Sampler)
The scenario is like this.
I want to print out the current path by "pwd" command.
After that, I want to make Dircetory named dir123 by "mkdir dir123" command.
Finally, I want to see all directories and files by "ls" command.

The screenshot is like this.
[OS Process Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5EVm.png)

And current Result by "View Results Tree" is like this.
[View Results Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3qXr.png)

It seems the first command "pwd" is the only command executed.
How can I execute more commands?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute 3 different commands so my expectation is that you should be using 3 OS Process Samplers.

If some reason you want/need/have to do it using single OS Process Sampler - you can use `&&` operator to connect these 3 commands like:

```
pwd && mkdir dir123 && ls
```

[image]

More information:

- [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)
- [Bash Reference Manual - List of Commands](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists)

Comment: THX A LOT!!
IT WORKED!
I appreciate you help! THANK YOU!